# Julia - Rewriting a CSV

Tags: csv, julia

Complete Julia newbie here.
I'd like to do some processing on a CSV. Something along the lines of:

```
using CSV

in_file = CSV.Source('/dir/in.csv')
out_file = CSV.Sink('/dir/out.csv')

for line in CSV.eachline(in_file)
    replace!(line, "None", "")
    CSV.writeline(out_file, line)
end
```

This is in pseudocode, those aren't existing functions.
Idiomatically, should I iterate on `1:CSV.countlines(in_file)`? Do a `while` and check something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want to do is replace a string in the line, you do not need any CSV parsing utilities. All you do is read the file line by line, replace, and write. So:

```
infile = "/path/to/input.csv"
outfile = "/path/to/output.csv"
out = open(outfile, "w+")
for line in readlines(infile)
     newline = replace(line, "a", "b")
     write(out, newline)
 end
 close(out)
```

This will replicate the pseudocode you have in your question.

If you need to parse and read the csv field by field, use the `readcsv` function in base.

```
data=readcsv(infile)
typeof(data) #Array{Any,2}
```

This will return the data in the file as a 2 dimensional array. You can process this data any way you want, and write it back using the `writecsv` function.

```
for i in 1:size(data,1) #iterate by rows 
      data[i, 1] = "This is " * data[i, 1]  # Add text to first column
end
writecsv(outfile, data)
```

Documentation for these functions:

- http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/io-network/?highlight=readcsv#Base.readcsv
- http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/io-network/?highlight=readcsv#Base.writecsv

Comment: Thank you! Great to come back from lunch and see you got exactly what you were hoping for.  
Followup - is there a way to `writecsv` with a header? I tried looking into the `writedlm` source but couldn't see how to do it.

Comment: [No](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/10284#issuecomment-75451713). Tried following the advice there, but for some reason the 1st content line doesn't get written:  
`data = readcsv(joinpath(file_path, in_file); header=true)  
map!(replace_nulls, data[1])  
out_f = open(joinpath(file_path, out_file), "a+")  
write(out_f, join(data[2], ","))  
# writecsv(joinpath(file_path, out_file), data[1])  
writecsv(out_f, data[1])
close(out_f)`

Comment: your call to `write()` uses a file handle, while your call to the first `writecsv()` uses a filename to the same file. `writecsv` will then open the file in write mode, which will ovewrite the first line. Instead of passing a the filename as a string to the `writecsv` function, pass the already open file handle (`out_f`) directly. `writecsv` is a generic function that takes both types of arguments.

Comment: @Ohad Please accept this answer if it answers your question, thanks.

Comment: thanks again for your help. Indeed that was a mistake, fixed now. For some reason I still need to rewrite the 1st line. Would be happy to hear any insights. Updated version: https://gist.github.com/ohadle/8db6ac0162779a28266de5f5eab46736

Comment: That is very strange. I tried similar code, and it write the headers without the need of line 6 in that gist. the only issue with your code is that you don't write out a new line after the headers, and hence the first line of the data comes out in the same line as the header. put in a `write(out_f, "\n")` after writing out the header.

Comment: That newline char did the trick. No need for that extra line now. Thanks!

Comment: which is the efficient way : a) opening and closing the input file many a times (or) b) reading all the lines to an array, processing in memory and writing back to file?

Comment: b) is certainly much much more efficient, provide the size of your file is smaller than the available memory on your machine. If that is not the case, you should stream it -- read one line of the original file, process it, write it to a new file. Then, when you finished all lines, delete the original file, and rename the new file to the old name.